# Ubuntu 12.04 shutdown does not finish

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, services, puppet

When i shutdown my ubuntu 12,04 appears the "shutdown screen" and it never finish, keep shutting down... i use "tab key" to see the log and the last line says "Stopping Puppet Agent"... and it never ends (i need to either keep pushing power button or disconnect the cord)

I Tried stopping the puppet service before shutdown but the problem persists..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This happened me twice: after installing RabbitMQ and `laptop-mode-tools`. Do you have any of those installed? Also try to uninstall puppet to check it is the culprit

Comment: i removed puppet but the problem persists :(

Comment: I experienced this trouble 2-3 times. Now that I know pressing 'Tab' will show the log, I will do that if I see the issue next time.

Comment: i removed several services and the problem persits :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after i removed several services (puppet, virtual box, etc). The solution was to uninstall the metaexploit framework i had installed since a long time ago...