# My PC seems stuck during shutting down. How can I fix this and have it power off?

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

I was running Ubuntu normally and one time I ran the command `startX` in my terminal and then my screen became black. So I powered off through the cable then when I reboot, it doesn't log in so I had to restart the lighdm (I think) now it does open.

If I shutdown it doesn't power off. It just shows the screen below for hours and hours, I can power off my PC by removing the cable only.

[image]

As suggested, on pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I see:

```
Stopping tor daemon...
Stopping postgreSQL 9.1 database server [ OK ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! When that image appears, press ``ESC`` key on keyboard. It will show what is happening. It should be stuck with something. Report back here and edit your question please.

Comment: @ThiagoPonte I updated the question with the last two lines I get when I pressed Esc

Comment: how to remove the metasploit framework ? http://askubuntu.com/a/200797/126748 as it helped this guy .. ( I have metasploit installed )

Comment: Stopping a (big) database can take quite a while. Check your database logs when turning it on/off using `sudo service postgresql stop` (or `start`). Does it show up as successful stop or not? And I doubt that metasploit has anything to do with it.

Comment: it shows a successful stop.
  * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server [ OK ]. and the same with start